# git lfs file once tracked by git cannot be tracked by lfs

Tags: git, git-lfs

I'm trying to use git LFS with a binary file (200 MB in size).
I think I have messed up adding it the first time, so it was tracked by git and not with git LFS.
Then I could not get git to track it with LFS at all.

I've thrown away that commit (`git reset --hard <commit_id>`) where the file was tracked without LFS and force pushed it to remote, deleting the pushed commit too.
Then I tried adding it with git LFS, but `git lfs status` always shows that it will not be tracked by LFS. (I tried varying the order in which I addthe .gitattributes file, copy in the binary into the repo, git adding the file, etc. I tried commiting .gitattributes first, then commiting the binary,..)
I then removed the commits I made, removed the binary from the local repo, then created an empty file with the same name and tracked it with LFS (to test my theory that maybe the problem is that git remembers this file name and to track it without LFS), and I finally saw that it does track it: `binary (LFS: e3b0c44)`. But then when I copied in the file contents of my binary into this file, and `git lfs status` shows this: `binary (LFS: e3b0c44 -> Git: 8a43985)`. This means it won't push it with LFS if I commit it, right?
Then lastly I tried appending a null byte to this file, thinking maybe git remembers that this file content should be mapped to a normal git file in the repo, but the result is the same, but now with a different hash after `Git:`.
All this time, the file name stayed tracked with LFS according to .gitattributes.

The file name has dots in it btw: `git lfs track "tensorflow-2.13.0-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl"`. But it was not a problem, the empty version was tracked by LFS.

**Edit**
I made another branch, modified the file, and uploaded it successfully with LFS. Since then, on the original branch when I modify the binary and execute `git lfs status` I get a different output for the file: `LFS: <hash> -> File: <other hash>` . Notice `File` instead of `Git`. Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to untrack by Git ?

```
git rm --cached **/*.xlsx
git add .
```

before track it again by `git lfs track "**/*.xlsx"`
Something like this
https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3421#issuecomment-446074602